# Incorrect version information after rebuilding

Tags: delphi, version

I am using Delphi XE3 to open a Delphi 5 project. And in the "Version Information" of the project, I can see there are many entries, such as "CompanyName", "ProductVersion", etc.. And I use "Auto generate build number" option.
However, after re-build the project, I find:

1. The build number does not increase automatically.
2. Most of the entries are not included. Only the "ProductVersion", "FileVersion" and "Language" are included. All other entries disappear.
3. The version information is incorrect. It should be 5.0.0.4, but the actual version is 1.0.0.0.

Why? I have tried "Do not change build number", "Auto increase build number", but all these options do not work.

Comment: This feature doesn't work very well. Don't use it. Roll your own as part of your build automation.

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the correct file? Perhaps you're looking and an old binary compiled before you changed any of version information settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by the fact that all version information is given for each build configuration and platform. Make sure that the data is entered correctly at all of these places.

Comment: In my project group, there are two projects. The strange thing is that the version info for project 1 is correct. But that for project 2 is incorrect. Therefore, I am trying to find the source files that are used to store the project settings(including the version info) and compare them accordingly.

Comment: After checking the files under the project directory, I think *.dproj is used to store the project settings. However, when I open one .dproj file in a plain text editor, I find there is only one section <VersionInfo> and <VersionInfoKeys> that are used to store the version. But since each project has "Debug" and "Release" configs, different configs use different versions info, why there are NOT two instances of <VersionInfo> and <VersionInfoKeys> for Debug and Release separately? I cannot understand.

Comment: The question is: Where is that version info stored? Actually 1.0.0.0 is the default when nothing is set.